# Structure Member Operator Error on Simple C Program

Tags: c, structure, dot-operator

I'm studying about structures, and having some error. I cannot figure out why. Please help me out.

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct data{
    int x;
    float y;
    float z;
} info;

info.x = 100;

struct data *ptr;
ptr = &info;

(*ptr).y = 5.5;
(*ptr).z = 1.0;

int main(void)
{
    printf("The first member's value is %d.\n", info.x);
    printf("The second member's value is %.1f.\n", info.y);
    printf("The third member's value is %.1f.\n", info.z);

    return 0;
}
```

The compiler error is

```
exercise112.c:10:5: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘.’ token
 info.x = 100;
     ^
exercise112.c:13:1: warning: data definition has no type or storage class
 ptr = &info;
 ^~~
exercise112.c:13:1: warning: type defaults to ‘int’ in declaration of ‘ptr’ [-Wimplicit-int]
exercise112.c:13:1: error: conflicting types for ‘ptr’
exercise112.c:12:14: note: previous declaration of ‘ptr’ was here
 struct data *ptr;
              ^~~
exercise112.c:13:7: warning: initialization makes integer from pointer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
 ptr = &info;
       ^
exercise112.c:13:7: error: initializer element is not computable at load time
exercise112.c:15:7: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘.’ token
 (*ptr).y = 5.5;
       ^
exercise112.c:16:7: error: expected ‘=’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘asm’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘.’ token
 (*ptr).z = 1.0;
       ^
```

1. Did I do definition, declaration, initialization or anything wrong?
2. I cannot figure out what the error messages are saying. what do they
   mean?

Comment: @om Outside a function you may place only declarations. So for example this statement ptr = &info; is incorrect outside main.

Comment: You need to put the code into a function. In general, only variable and function declarations can be outside a function in C.

Comment: So I fixed it. it complies without error. but now when executing a.out, the result is "Segmentation fault (core dumped)". I read that it happens because I was trying to access the memory that I don't have an access to. Can anyone give me some guides?